# Correct installation/integration of Google Chrome with Watir-Cucumber

Tags: google-chrome, cucumber, watir

I am new to `Watir` earlier when we were using `Selenium` it was easy, just needed to set the `System.setProperty(` to let the chrome run. 
 But here with `Watir` it seems little difficult.

I tried:

**hooks.rb**

```
Before do
    puts "inside hooks in before"
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
end
```

Downloaded chrome binary and placed it in **C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application** and copy pasted this path in **Environment Variables >> Path**.

But instead of giving this error:

```
Unable to find the chromedriver
executable. Please download the server from http://code.google.com/p/chromedrive
r/downloads/list and place it somewhere on your PATH.
```

It is giving

```
RuntimeError: Unable to pick a platform for the provided browser.
nil was passed to the PageObject constructor instead of a valid browser object.
```

How can I run tests with Chrome, how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hooks.rb** is fine. It's just you mis-understood the **PATH**.

Looks like you are on windows, so you not need to edit `Environment Variables >> Path`.

You just have paste the downloaded Google Chrome binary file in `C:\Windows` directory and it will work.

Comment: If you are still having problems, check the installation documentation: https://github.com/watir/watirbook/blob/master/manuscript/installation/windows.md#chrome

Comment: @ŽeljkoFilipin I got that, but the problem is that I don't want to hardcode the path. I want where ever my project goes it works, whether it is unix, linux or windows.